# How to compose a postgres jsonb array from individual elements

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, jsonb

I want to create a postgres jsonb array: `[{"score": 4500, "match": 45}, {"score": 2505, "match": 467}, {"score": 967, "match": 678}]` and I have the individual elements `{"score": 4500, "match": 45}, {"score": 2505, "match": 467}` etc with me.

I don't want to explode it to key value pairs and then build a jsonb object. Is there a way in postgres 9.3?

Comment: What do you mean you have them "with you"? Are they stored in a jsonb column with one element per row or something? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsonb` was [introduced in Postgres 9.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/release-9-4.html). In Postgres 9.3.x you can stick only with `json`:

```
WITH json_elements(data) AS ( VALUES
  ('{"score": 4500, "match": 45}'::JSON),
  ('{"score": 2505, "match": 467}'::JSON)
)
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(je.data)) AS result
FROM json_elements je;
```

Result is :

```
                            result                            
--------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"match": 45, "score": 4500},{"match": 467, "score": 2505}]
(1 row)
```